# How can this all fit into 64kb?

Tags: assembly

So, I am here at assembly 2011 and there was this demo played: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69Xjc7eklxE&feature=player_embedded

It's one single file only, it says that in the rules. So I repeat, how have they made this to fit into so small file?

Comment: Can this demo be downloaded? I would like to see how it works when run locally.

Comment: Yes, you can find that demo here: ftp://ftp.untergrund.net/users/atzAdmin/fltatz_uncovering_static.zip

Comment: Of course there *are* several megabytes of system libraries without which this thing wouldn't be able draw a single polygon...

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this will run in Crossover/Wine? :P

Comment: As someone who actively creates 64kB intros, I've written this article: http://www.ctrl-alt-test.fr/?p=494 (How can demoscene productions be so small?).

TL;DR: procedural generation, compression, and a lot of extra work.

Comment: @Laurent Do you do it all in assembly? I was playing with this a while back in C and basically wrote something no more complex than Pong while basically spending almost all of my time figuring out how to write C code without the CRT. Then after disabling things like loop unrolling and function inlining, I still got a 12 kilobyte binary and threw in the towel. :-D It's actually the basics of eliminating libs and cramming down the instructions that has me confused. I know a little bit more about procedural generation and so forth with the data, but don't know how to crunch the code down so much.

Comment: @TeamUpvote No, it's all C++. To go below 12kB, you need to get rid of the standard library. If you use Visual C++, you can find examples here: https://github.com/laurentlb/Ctrl-Alt-Test/tree/master/F and http://www.iquilezles.org/code/framework64k/framework64k.htm.

Comment: I’ve looked at squeezing exe sizes before, it’s takes a bit of research to get it down and it changes a bit from one version of Windows to the next.   I’d say you have to have a passion for it to do so on a regular basis.

Comment: Another cool one is an oldie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.kkrieger

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's [procedural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation) based. The content is not included in the exe, only the rules of how to draw it. When launched, the program draws what it needs to at runtime it's not pre-rendered or pre-saved in any form.

This is the same method used by [Elite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_%28video_game%29) to create a vast universe of star systems, etc.

It's pretty amazing what is possible today using procedural generation, i think games will feature more of this in the future.

Comment: I just thought that the textures are pretty accurate. So they just draw it with code and without any texture files I guess?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: For these kind of demos the sound is also generated from code (no samples). Everything is synthesized on the fly... and of course some credits and fade scenes allow heavy precomputation :)

Comment: As a former 3d artist, I've been wanting procedural generated textures to be included as standard tool-set in mainstream 3d art programs for a long time. Probably the closest is by using the built-in scripting language....

Comment: You might be interested in such stuff as [Project Frontier](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=11874) and [Procedural World](http://procworld.blogspot.com/), which are two approaches to the same problem through procedural generation.

Comment: @Darknight, most 3D art programs I've looked at do include procedural textures (noise and gradient being some of them, being able to mix textures you can be creative and create a lot). I know that 3DSMax, Maya and Blender do have a scripting API's available.

Comment: @Spoike, :) I'm aware of the basic procedural textures, however I was referring to more complex procedural textures, e.g realistic damaged concrete, infinite grass (that does not look like damn tiles!), complex organic wood etc.. I've also worked with [ Max, Maya, Blender, TrueSpace, C4D ]

Comment: Another (mostly) procedural game http://www.infinity-universe.com/

Answer (score 10):

As @Gary Willoughby says, it extensively procedural.

Also, there is significant hand `asm` coding involved, along with extensive knowledge of how many of the windows/platform of choice systems work internally.

There is also a 4K demo category, if you want to see even more extreme examples of compact code.

Some of the DemoScene groups release their demos online, where you can download them and play them if you want.

[Conspiracy](http://conspiracy.hu/)
[farb-rausch](http://www.farb-rausch.de/)

Also See [Wikipedia on the history of the DemoScene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demo_%28computer_programming%29)

<sup>Note - a lot of the demos will cause your antivirus to *freak out*. Basically it seems pretty much all demos use packed .exe files, and most of the demo groups roll their own packers. Unfortunately, because a lot of AV companies are lame, they generally claim that any packed binary executable is a virus of some sort.</sup>

Comment: I'm left wondering what AV company you have in mind as even possibly being non-lame...

Comment: +1 Awesome stuff. Do they use the Nvidea APIs or draw directly to the graphics card?

Comment: They usually set up a minimal OpenGL framework and kick off some shaders to do the rest

Comment: It's seriously impressive stuff. I think if I was about 15 years younger this would be what I'd spend my spare time doing.

Comment: Here are some assembly 2011 demos: http://archive.assembly.org/2011

Comment: Most 64kB intros are written in C++. I know a few that are written in Rust. Assembly is not really used or necessary for 64kB intros. In 4kB intros, assembly can be useful - but many of them are actually in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Like everyone is saying they widely relies on procedural generated code, but there's even more about this demo in particular, if you pause and look at some details, lets see for example those walls: [look that bricks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69Xjc7eklxE&feature=player_detailpage#t=204s) and how light reflects on them. They look natural.

That's because they are using a lot of vertex shaders and fragment shaders to bring life to the generated content.

I spent [some](http://pastie.org/2341980) time trying to understand how they make such things, and feel amazed with every piece of code I grab from those demos.

BTW, when doing those demos they also use compression tools to squeeze even more. check this compilation process:

```
all:
nasm -f bin -o intro main.asm
nasm -f bin -o stub stub.asm
gzip -n --best intro
advdef -z -4 intro.gz
cat stub intro.gz > intro
chmod +x intro
rm intro.gz
rm stub
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a [PowerPoint presentation](http://directtovideo.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/gdc_2012_released.ppt) of how the rendering was done in this specific demo. This alone doesn't explain how everything fits into 64 kilobytes, but is the key for how the geometry was created in such a little space.

There is also lots of interesting read in his [blog](http://directtovideo.wordpress.com/) about his other demoscene productions.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated, a lot of this relies on procedurally generated assets.

There is another element to it, which is compression. 4k and 64k demos use highly specialized executable compressors. The most famous of these are kkrunchy by farbrausch (for 64ks) and crinkler by TBC & Loonies (for 4ks). Moreover, modern demos make heavy use of shaders, which are plain text and thus get dramatically smaller after compression.

Now, as far as integration in video games is concerned, the main problem is that all this takes time. Generating procedural content takes time, and extracting the executable takes a huge amount of time. And people generally have more space on their hard drives than time to spend waiting for the game to load, so I don't think we will be seeing lots of this in widely available games anytime soon.